# Failed to mount Partitions - Not authorized to perform operation

Tags: debian, partition

I have Debian-9 dual booted with Windows-8.

When I try to access to my hard-drive's partitions, it gives me :

> Failed to mount Not authorized to perform

I tried `mount /dev/sda4`

> mount: can't find /dev/sda4 in /etc/fstab

My `/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=7393b8df-fc39-4649-9c0d-e818eb77fe8a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

I added `/dev/sda4       /media     ext4    defaults        0       2` and it didnt boot.

What am I missing here? usb drivers are mounted without any error.

My system specs

```
Linux userA 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
9.4
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `mount` command you need to provide:

1. The device.
2. The directory where you want to mount it (which must already exist).
3. If the filesystem is not detected, then you'll need to provide the filesystem type.
4. Any additional optional filesystem-specific arguments.

For example, assuming `/media` and `/dev/sda4` both exist and `/dev/sda4` contains an ext4 filesystem, you can mount it with this command: `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media`, or more explicitly as `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda4 /media`

`sudo` is necessary because on Linux only root can mount without an `/etc/fstab` entry. To read a novel of all the ways to use `mount`, run `man mount`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I had to change permission to other users and even with that I can not copy/paste files to there. Also its gone after reboot.

Comment: Using the `mount` command is for temporary mounts. You need an entry in `/etc/fstab` to make it persistent. Also, since you have your CDROM to mount at `/media/cdrom` I don't recommend mounting the HD on `/media` Use `man fstab` to learn more.